# Receive HTTP response on socket in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, socket.io, httpresponse

I want to send a post request and receive its response on a socket.

The response is a stream and response is only received when some event happens. I want response of post request to be attached to a socket so that I can read from socket and know the response continuously.

Note: The stream in requests is not working for me I need to try this with sockets only.

**EDIT**:I want something like following

```
s = socket.socket()
host = 'localhost'
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))
r = requests.post("someurl")
r.redirect_response((host,port))
#or
s.connect("HTTP POST") #I don't know how to do this though

while True:
    print s.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Do you have any code to post, so people can see what you've tried?

Comment: Added a little code what I want!!

Comment: Why do you want to do this with low level socket handling instead of an http client library ?

Comment: @JoãoPinto because the post call I'm making subscribes to a server for event triggers it is a blocking POST request. It does not send any output unless there is some event. Please check out my question [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978960/get-continuous-response-of-post-request-in-python?noredirect=1#comment61516185_36978960)